# How to calculate scrollbar distance relative to nested div content

Tags: jquery, css

So we've ran into this issue in an app we're currently building.

We have a `div` whose height is calculated based on the viewport (lets say it's 800px to make things simple) and has the property of `overflow-y: auto`.

Inside this `div` we have a container in which our content is displayed, that is typically longer than it's parent `div`. When the user scrolls to the bottom of the content, we trigger a method to load more data in (think infinite scroll). The issue we're running into is once the scrollbar of the parent `div` is past the original trigger point, every subsequent scroll action fires the method again because the scroll offset is greater than the parent `div` height.

Is there a way to calculate the offset relative to the height of the content within the inner `div`? We'd like to base this off percentages somehow, so say when the scrollbar reaches 98% of the way to the bottom, fire the method to load more data, then recalculate the scroll position based off the new content height. Our current function is as follows:

```
// Smart Loading Method
Flight.$.listViewAjaxLoader = function() {
console.log ('Ajax Loader Method Called');
var contentLoadTriggered = false,
  listViewPane = $('#agenda_viewer'),
  offset = 0,
  limit = 25;

$(listViewPane).scroll( function() {
contentLoadTriggered = false;

console.log( $(listViewPane).scrollTop(), $(listViewPane).height() );

if ( $(listViewPane).scrollTop() >= $(listViewPane).height() && contentLoadTriggered == false ) {
  contentLoadTriggered = true;
  console.log('load trigger status:' + contentLoadTriggered);
}

if ( contentLoadTriggered == true ) {
  offset = offset + limit;
      $.get("removed for security", function(response) {
    var assetsArray = response.data.assets,
    assetCount = assetsArray.length,
    start =    Flight.view_state.campaigns[Flight.$._globals.thisCampaign].list_view.start,
    dateFormatForCampaign = 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    newData = '';

    start = moment(start, dateFormatForCampaign);

    for (var i = 0; i < assetCount; i++) {
      var asset = assetsArray[i],
          flight = asset.flight;

      newData += Flight.$.agendaAssetRowHTML(flight, asset, start);
    }
    $(listViewPane).append(newData);
    $('.agenda-toggle-all.agenda-collapse-all').trigger('click');
  });
}
});
}
```

Here is a quick mockup of how the elements are displayed and layed out
[image]

Comment: use something based on `$(listViewPane).scrollTop()/$(listViewPane).height()`, like if that's over 0.85 or something

Comment: We've tried similar attempts at a solution, the issue is that once we add more content, the problem seems to be that $(listViewPanel).height() should actually be a value based off the inner div height, but we can't seem to get a height from it (as it's not set and is dependent on content).

Comment: hmm. i don't use jQuery much, but i think `listViewPane.scrollTop/ listViewPane.offsetHeight` is the figure you want and relatively x-browser compat these days...

Comment: We've figured out that the issue is coming from the height of the container not changing in the DOM after we add the new data. When we log the content and container height before and after the data is loaded, the  values remain the same. Is there a way to force the DOM to update the height?

Comment: are you logging `offsetHeight`? that should increase when new content makes the scroll bar narrower. if not, then i don't know what's going on, but i guess you could always take the last element and get its `.offsetTop` to approximate the over-all height.

Comment: @dandavis That's the issue we were running into, the height value wasn't updating in the DOM after the new content was loaded. We finally figured out scrollHeight got us the value we were looking for, thanks for all the suggestions, they at least got us on the right track. Posted the answer down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we finally figured this out. We ended up using scrollHeight to get the length of the scrollbar instead of the divs height value (since the DOM wasn't being updated for some reason), and then did the math using that value, with the formula ending up as:

```
listViewPane = $('#agenda_viewer');
var scrollPercentage = ( listViewPane.scrollTop() / ( listViewPane[0].scrollHeight - listViewPane.height() ) )* 100 ;
```